# Emulator Doesn't run hello run app

Tags: java, android, eclipse, emulation

Today I began using Andriod SDK on eclipse and I had a lot of problems installing everything, but finally it all works fine.

Now I made a new project and changed nothing within the project and so. I run it, and keep my emulator open(from the run before) so I won't get a fault because the emulator is still loading the library while eclipse is running the app on the emulator. It all works fine and the application is in the emulator. When I start the app, I get the fault and the emulator says : `unfortunately, Hello world has stopped working`. What is the problem that I cannot run an app (even without any changes.. ) on my emulator?

This is what log cat says:

> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386): Process: com.example.sssssss, PID: 1386
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386): at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.themifyContext(AppCompatViewInflater.java:221)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386): at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:84)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386): at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:938)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386): at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:992)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.generateLayout(PhoneWindow.java:3489)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.installDecor(PhoneWindow.java:3561)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.getDecorView(PhoneWindow.java:1916)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:149)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:60)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at com.example.sssssss.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:12)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5937)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.sssssss-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   ... 28 more
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):       at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):       at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):       ... 29 more
>
> 11-14 23:08:51.661: E/AndroidRuntime(1386):   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available

Hopefully you guys could help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NoClassDefFoundError, as you could see ont [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java), is cause by a class you have on compile time, but not on runtime.

You didn't change anything, but make sure your structure was really an Android project.

PS : Also, as I did the same some years ago, you should give a try to Android Studio, it have a lot of useful tricks Eclipse didn't have and everything is made for Android. You should also try Genymotion, as their emulators are fastest you could imagin...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i also installed the andriod studio. But it is for my school project and i have to use java in eclipse, so i think i have to use the eclipse for andriod also..

Comment: did you try with a real android phone ? (To know if the problem comes from the emulator) Do your project include any external library ?

Comment: it works now, the problem is the emulator i guess. it worked on real phone, THanks!